# Drawing and labeling angles in an axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am curious about the misinterpretation of `TikZ` commands to draw and label an angle in an `axis` environment. If, in the following code, I have $\theta$ drawn using the commands,

```
\draw[draw=blue] (A) ++(120:4mm) arc (120:0:4mm);
\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:5.5mm);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};
```

the angle and label are displayed as expected.  I have, though,

```
\draw[draw=blue] (A) ++(120:0.4) arc (120:0:0.4);
\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:0.55);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};
```

and a mess is displayed.  I understand that using the `axis` environment is superfluous - I am using it just to draw the axes.  As I said, I am curious.  (I know that I could use `tkz-euclice`.  I am using this as an opportunity to get familiar with `TikZ`.  I would prefer to avoid using this package, anyway.)

By the way, I typeset the vertex `A` properly with     `\node at (0.25,-0.25){$A$};`, without units, and I typeset the vertex `B` properly with `\node at (3.5,-2.5mm){$B$};`, with units.  I was told that specifying coordinates with dimensions within an axis environment would be misinterpreted.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-1.5:5,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

%A triangle is drawn on the Cartesian plane. One side of the triangle is along
%the positive x-axis, and another side of the triangle is drawn in Quadrant II.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at ({5*cos(120)},{5*sin(120)});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The labels for A and B are typeset.
\node at (0.25,-0.25){$A$};
\node at (3.5,-2.5mm){$B$};
%The label for C is typeset.
\coordinate (label_C_left) at ($(C)!-4mm!(B)$);
\coordinate (label_C_right) at ($(C)!-4mm!(A)$);
\coordinate (label_C) at ($(label_C_left)!0.5!(label_C_right)$);
\node[blue] at ($(C)!2.5mm!(label_C)$){$C$};


%Angles are drawn for $\theta$ and its supplement.
\draw[draw=blue] (A) ++(120:0.4) arc (120:0:0.4);
\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:0.55);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};
\draw[draw=blue,dash dot] (A) ++(180:0.6) arc (180:120:0.6);
\coordinate (label_for_supplement_to_theta) at (150:0.75);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_supplement_to_theta){$\pi - \theta$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn.
\coordinate (U) at ($(-2.5,0)!3mm!45:(A)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(A)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(C)$);


\draw[dashed] (C) -- (-2.5,0);

%Braces indicating the distances that C is from the axes are typeset. To give
%them the appearance of being typeset over the axes, they are first typeset
%in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the thickness of the
%brace that is actually typeset.
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C);
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);


\coordinate (label_for_5_sin_theta) at ($({5*cos(120)},{2.5*sin(120)}) + (-2.5mm-10pt,0pt)$);
\node[anchor=east] at (label_for_5_sin_theta){$r\sin\theta$};
\coordinate (label_for_5_cos_theta) at (-1.25,-2.5mm-10pt);
\node at (label_for_5_cos_theta){$r\cos\theta$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you read page 350 of the `pgfplots` manual? The fact that you are using `width=5in`, for example, is certainly going to alter the units. But, also, as Aleanno pointed out, it is a matter of the origin's location, too.

Comment: @cfr  I will look now.  (I have been editing another post.)  Is this the web site?  `http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf` Where did Aleanno leave a comment?

Comment: I meant the answer to your other question. Best is `texdoc pgfplots`. What you are seeing is a result of `pgfplots` - not TikZ itself. As I said before, the `axis` environment is specialised and the coordinate systems used there do not map one-one onto TikZ coordinate systems unless set up specifically to do so. That is, unless you follow the restrictions explained on page 350.

Comment: @cfr  Please give me the web site to the manual to which you are referring.  I will have a similar post in about 15 minutes.  I will send you a ping.  (I see that you deleted most of our conversation.  That is fine.  I made many edits to my original post during our discussion.  Again, thanks for your patience.  I will delete this comment, too.)

Comment: It is not deleted. It just moved to chat.

Comment: @cfr Please give me the web site to the manual to which you are referring.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to use the axis environment to draw the axis, then don't try to do anything else with it.  Note: the scope is used to shift the origin.

I also simplified your angle labels.  Later I came back and simplified all of the labels.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-1.5:5,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[shift={(origin)}]
%A triangle is drawn on the Cartesian plane. One side of the triangle is along
%the positive x-axis, and another side of the triangle is drawn in Quadrant II.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at ({5*cos(120)},{5*sin(120)});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

\coordinate (D) at (A-|C);% horizontal to (A), vertical to (C)

%The labels for A and B are typeset.
\node[below right] at (A){$A$};
\node[below] at (B){$B$};
%The label for C is typeset.
\node[blue,above left] at (C) {$C$};


%Angles are drawn for $\theta$ and its supplement.
\draw[draw=blue] (A) ++(120:0.4) arc (120:0:0.4)
  node[midway,above right,inner sep=2pt,font={\footnotesize}]{$\theta$};
\draw[draw=blue,dash dot] (A) ++(180:0.6) arc (180:120:0.6)
  node[midway,left,inner sep=2pt,font={\footnotesize}]{$\pi - \theta$};

%A right-angle mark is drawn.
\draw[dash dot] (D) +(0,3mm) -- +(3mm,3mm) -- +(3mm,0);

\draw[dashed] (C) -- (D);

%Braces indicating the distances that C is from the axes are typeset. To give
%them the appearance of being typeset over the axes, they are first typeset
%in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the thickness of the
%brace that is actually typeset.
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=.5em,amplitude=.5em}] (D) -- (C);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=.5em,amplitude=.5em}] (D) -- (C)
  node[midway,left=1em] {$r\sin\theta$};;
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=1ex,amplitude=1ex,mirror}] (D) -- (A);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=1ex,amplitude=1ex,mirror}] (D) -- (A)
  node[midway,below=2ex] {$r\cos\theta$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: axis and scope]

Comment: This is an efficient modification to my code.  The display is exactly what I want.  Thanks.  I see that you added `\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);` and a `scope` environment with the option `shift={(origin)}`.  What does adding the `\coordinate` command within the `axis` environment do? I guess the option to the scope environment aligns the origin of the `axis` environment with the origin of the `scope` environment.

Comment: The axis environment uses its own coordinate system.  \coordinate records (0,0) in the axis environment in terms of screen coordinates, and more importantly as a global value.  Without the \begin{scope}[shift={(origin)}] the rest of the plot would be centered about the lower left hand corner of the axis.